# Name of $H|a\rangle=n|a\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I was wondering if the form $$H\vert a\rangle=n\vert a\rangle$$ has a proper name. I am familiar with each part like the Hermitian matrix, eigenvalue and eigenstate, but is there a word to classify the whole form? If you need any clarification ask, and thanks for reading.

If you understood the first part I also would like to know if there is a name to classify the multiple eigenvalues that fall under a Hermitian matrix, so if $$H\vert a\rangle=n\vert a\rangle$$ and also $$H\vert b\rangle=c\vert b\rangle,$$ then is there a word to refer to both $\vert a\rangle$ and $\vert b\rangle$ that share the same Hermitian matrix?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please provide names for the symbols you are using, use the built-in TeX editor and format your question in a way that makes reading it easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation

$$ H |a\rangle = n |a\rangle $$

is called the **eigenvalue equation** or **eigenequation** for the operator/hermitian matrix $H$. The eigenvectors $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ are part of the **set of eigenvectors** of the operator/matrix.